# mat-table how to know if it's overflown

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-table that can overflow and show the scroll bar or not.

But I want to add an icon when it happens, so, I need to know if it's or not to include the condition:

```
<mat-table></mat-table>
<mat-icon *ngIf="isOverflown"></mat-icon>
```

How can I check this property?